# Running SyncAdapter when internet connection is available

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, offline-mode

I am working on an Android app that sends geo-coordinates and some other data to server each time the user changes his position.

To handle off-line mode I've been told to use the [Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) framework but I still don't know how to fire a `requestSync` call each time the network is enabled and call my `sendToServer` method.

I've been thinking about running the `SyncAdapter` on demand but referring to [Android official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html#RunOnDemand) that's not recommended !

Any suggestions guys ?

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea behind the Sync Adapter framework is that you dont have to use timers and so on to directly call your sync code (The android framework does it for you in a very efficient way). But still when necessary you can broadcast sync request from within your app to initiate sync. like this:

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(syncAccount, SYNC_AUTHORITY, Bundle.EMPTY);
```